# ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby

I have written a program for codewars that finds the lowest two integers and returns the sum of them:

```
def sum_two_smallest_numbers(numbers)
  array_lowest = [0, 0]
  main_iterate = 2
  array_lowest[0] = sum_two_smallest_numbers[0]
  array_lowest[1] = sum_two_smallest_numbers[1]
  until main_iterate == sum_two_smallest_numbers.length - 1 #maybe -2, or 0
    if sum_two_smallest_numbers[main_iterate] < array_lowest[0]
      array_lowest[0] = sum_two_smallest_numbers[main_iterate]
      main_iterate += 1
    elsif sum_two_smallest_numbers[main_iterate] < array_lowest[1]
      array_lowest[1] = sum_two_smallest_numbers[main_iterate]
      main_iterate += 1
    else
      main_iterate += 1
    end
  end
  return array_lowest[0] + array_lowest[1]
end
```

to fulfill tests as follows:

```
Test.assert_equals(sum_two_smallest_numbers([5, 8, 12, 18, 22]), 13) 
Test.assert_equals(sum_two_smallest_numbers([7, 15, 12, 18, 22]), 19) 
Test.assert_equals(sum_two_smallest_numbers([25, 42, 12, 18, 22]), 30)
```

It complains about my first line (this was provided along with an `end`), and if I replace `numbers` with any actual numbers, as in the test cases, it throws this:

```
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you can't replace `(numbers)` with actual numbers becausse that's the list of arguments. The only place you can supply actual numbers is when you _call_ the function (not when you define it)

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried calling the function. Now it sees a single number or array as 0 arguments, but more than 1 as too many. I can only get 0 or 2+.

Comment: You're going to like Ruby. Here you can write `[5, 8, 12, 18, 22].min(2).sum #=> 13`. See [Array#min](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-min) and [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: That's such an elegant solution, and here's me reprogramming the wheel! I'm liking it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursively calling `sum_two_smallest_numbers` with no arguments., and it requires an argument. Each time you write `sum_two_smallest_numbers`, that's a method invocation. When you write `sum_two_smallest_numbers[0]`, that's a method invocation with no arguments, the `[0]` would access the 0'th element of the returned value, if the invocation succeeded.

It seems like you might have wanted `numbers[0]`, `sum_two_smallest_numbers[0]`.

Comment: That's done it! Many thanks for the clear explanation.